# Preview or Download PDF does not work in PHP Code

Tags: php, google-chrome, pdf, firefox

I know this question is old and there is a lot of code here, but I tested it several and none worked for me. I'm trying to make it available to view or download a PDF file (whichever works) in a php code. In Microsoft Edge works without any problem any code, but already in Google Chrome or in Firefox simply no code works in its most current versions. If someone can lend a hand, thank you very much!

```
$url = 'pdf/'.$file.'.pdf';
$content = file_get_contents($url);

header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($content));
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="PDF.pdf"');
header('Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
ini_set('zlib.output_compression','0');

ob_clean();
flush();

$fp = fopen ('pdf/'.$file.'.pdf', 'r');

while (!feof($fp)) {
   $buff = fread($fp, 1024);
   print $buff;
}
exit;

die($content);
```

Comment: What does "not work" mean? What actually happens?

Comment: Side note: `die($content);` doesn't do anything, since you have an `exit;` above it.

Comment: Well, it just happens that nothing happens. When you click the button to display the PDF, the browser simply gives you a refresh like you would run the code, but it does not open anything. Already in Microsoft Edge opens normally ... I have the tag 'die', but still not open the PDF.

Comment: Try to change `Content-Disposition` to `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="PDF.pdf"` and `Content-Type` to `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`. That should at least trigger a download (which you said was OK).

Comment: I'm making all the changes you're suggesting, but outside Microsoft Edge where all of these changes still work perfectly, in the most up-to-date Google Chrome and Firefox, nothing done, does not open, or does not download. I'm running my Webserver on CentOS 6.10.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php
$url = 'pdf/'.$file.'.pdf';

header('Content-Type: application/pdf');

@readfile($url);
```

It works for me

read readfile(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: _Note:_ Using `@` to suppress errors is bad and will make it a pain to debug if something goes wrong. You should properly handle the errors instead.

Comment: I just tested the vieroli code, but it still only works on Microsoft Edge. I'm getting my hair straight already .. ^^

Comment: It works on chrome for me. Can you open this page on chrome ? http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf

Comment: This page I can open in Chrome yes Vieroli, why?